# Making RSA signature secure

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a system to authorize http requests using RSA, so far I have this. It works, but I was thinking, what is stopping someone from creating a completely valid token of their own then sending it to my server? How do I make sure a signature is a signature that my server created?

```html
const {publicKey, privateKey} = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", loginTokenKeyOptions)

const tokenPayload = {
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 8),

    loginMethod: "PhoneNumber",
    loginID: user.PhoneNumber,
    accountTags: user.AccountTags
}

console.log(typeof(publicKey))

//Create signature
const tokenBase64 = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(tokenPayload)).toString("base64")
const signature = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256").update(tokenBase64).sign({key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING}, "base64")
const token = tokenBase64 + "." + publicKey + "." + signature

console.log(JSON.stringify(tokenPayload))
console.log(tokenBase64)
console.log(signature)

//Validate signature
const tokenComponents = token.split(".")
const isValidToken = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA256").update(tokenComponents[0]).verify({key: tokenComponents[1], padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING}, signature, "base64")

console.log(tokenComponents)
console.log(isValidToken)
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at JWT

Comment: @BrianPursley already implemented that successfully but I'm trying to learn more about how the security works under the hood

Comment: it works by having a *secret* which only the server knows.. without that an attacker cant possibly create a valid signature. signature validation comes with re-signing the data with the same *secret* to produce the same signature

Comment: But how is the validation done with the public key? If someone created a valid key themselves using the code above then sent that key to my server, the key would be considered valid even though it's not, right?

Comment: Normally a web server would not generate a key pair on every request, the key pair would be generated once and stored in a secure way for the server to use. Only if someone knows your private key could they craft a token that will be verified by your public key

Comment: @BrianPursley That's what I'm currently doing.I generate a key pair when the user logs in, then return the token + public key. But can't someone generate their own key pair, use the exact same payload as me then send that "forged" token to my system? How can I be sure that I created the token, not someone else, without the private key?

Comment: I don’t know how else to say this, but you need to keep the private key secure. If some else uses a different key pair and tries to send you a token signed with their key pair, then it will fail your verification step because they didn’t sign it with your private key.

Comment: Doesn’t `generateKeyPairSync` return a different key pair each time you call it?

Comment: @BrianPursley Yes, a random public and private key. I'm just confused on what I should be doing with them. I use the private key to sign the token, then it's forgotten about. I send the token and public key to the client. Now what would be the correct way to validate a token server side, ideally in a stateless way, and also make sure that it was my server that created the token in the first place?